# Linq Where Condtion For Different Types

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that is derived from ProfileBase. This list can contains an instance of Profile,,DynamicViewProfile because both are derived from ProfileBase

But If the item type is DynamicViewProfile, i must use NodeName, if Profile then I should use DocName

```
profileListsForSearch = profileLists.Where(stringToCheck =>
((Profile)stringToCheck).DocName.Contains(searchBar.Text)).ToList();
```

So this is for profile and it is OK, but if the list contains DynamicViewProfile objects then i have an exception, because docname is null and i need to get NodeName

I hope my questions is clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about LINQ here - you basically write the same code as you would normally, using `is` or `as`:

```
string searchText = searchBar.Text;
profileListsForSearch = profileLists
    .Where(profile =>
        profile is Profile 
        ? ((Profile)profile).DocName.Contains(searchText)
        : ((DynamicViewProfile)profile).NodeName.Contains(searchText))
    .ToList();
```

That's assuming those are the only two types involved. If your list contains some other type, you'd get an `InvalidCastException`.

However, this is pretty ugly - it feels like `ProfileBase` should expose some property or method which indicates the general name - and then that could be implemented to return `DocName` in `Profile` and `NodeName` in `DynamicViewProfile`. Then you'd just need:

```
string searchText = searchBar.Text;
profileListsForSearch = profileLists
    .Where(profile => profile.Name.Contains(searchText))
    .ToList();
```

It's also future-proof in terms of adding new subclasses of `ProfileBase` - and generally a cleaner use of polymorphism. Every time you need to cast - particularly conditionally casting to one thing or the other - consider whether a common method/property is feasible to make it cleaner.

Comment: jeez, how can you type that so fast. I'm starting to think you have some "mental" keyboard, not the old hardware things we have :)

Comment: As I said in another comment, I cannot change the classes, because they come from WCF service. And you are right that I can have an exception. But types are certain so it will not be problem. I knew that I should cast types but never had an experience to do it in Where condition :) Thank you

Comment: @unbalanced: WCF generated types are partial, right? In that case, you can add the appropriate properties to do it the clean way...

Comment: Surely, I generate a dynamic proxy using silverlight tool (slsvcutil) for xamarin ios in c#. But I do not to add anything to this dynamic proxy, because when the service is updated, I have to re-generate a dynamic proxy again and need to add this property.. :) Then this is a better way for not. Thank you

Comment: @unbalanced: No, you don't need to change the *generated* code at all, assuming the types are generated as partial (which they should be). You add *separate* source code which contributes members to the partial types. You can regenerate the code as often as you like, and your extra source code won't be affected. This won't help if the generated code doesn't use partial types though.

Comment: Aha I see now.. Mmm let me think about it. Thank you for your nice advices.

Comment: by the meantime, I will look for your book :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is` to check the object and the use the `ternary` operator to apply the condition on the object.

```
var result = profileLists.Where(stringToCheck =>stringToCheck is Profile ? 
                           ((Profile)stringToCheck).DocName.Contains(searchBar.Text)
                           : ((DynamicViewProfile)stringToCheck).NodeName.Contains(searchBar.Text)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
profileListsForSearch = profileLists.Where(p => 
{
  if(p is Profile) return ((Profile)p).DocName.Contains(searchBar.Text));
  if(p is DynamicViewProfile) return ((DynamicViewProfile)p).NodeName.Contains(searchBar.Text)); 
  return false; 
}).ToList();
```

You can check the types. But that really only means your class hierarchy is broken. If you derive, you should never be forced to explicitely check for a type.

Instead, you could have a property in your base class called `FilterText` which is implemented by the base class as `return DocName;` and by the derived class as `return NodeName;`. Then your code would look like this:

```
profileListsForSearch = profileLists.Where(p => p.FilterText.Contains(searchBar.Text)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, But I cannot change the classes because It comes from webservice